# Generating query for multiple table by reading csv file in python using pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create sql query based on csv file. The file layout is below

| DB_Name | Table_Name | Col_Name | Key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZDB | ABC | C1 | Y |
| XYZDB | ABC | C2 | N |
| XYZDB | ABC | C3 | Y |
| XYZDB | DEF | C1 | N |
| XYZDB | DEF | C2 | Y |
| XYZDB | DEF | C3 | Y |

The output should be as below:

```
select count(*) from abc where C1 is null or c3 is null;

select count(*) from def where C3 is null or c3 is null;
```

---

below is the code snippet:

```
Non_Null_cols = df.loc[df['Key'] == 'Y', 'col_name'].unique()
Non_null_colmn_nm = ', '.join(Non_Null_cols)
for db_name, table_name in zip(df["DB_NAME"], df["TABLE_NAME"].unique()):
    Non_Null_cols = df.loc[df['Key'] == 'N', 'col_name'].unique()
    Non_null_colmn_nm = ', '.join(Non_Null_cols)
    with vertica_python.connect(**conn_info) as connection:
       query = f"select count(*) as NUll_check from {db_name}.{table_name} where {Non_null_colmn_nm} is null;".replace(","," is null or ")
        print(query)
```

Issue is its mapping columns of table 2 to table1